# Arduino Nano For Home Automation

Tags: arduino-nano

My question is about the arduino Nano or Micro and the smallest and cheapest way to control a bigger power source. I would wire it with a socket so that I could send a command from the board and a light would turn on for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relay is a common way to allow a smaller power source to safely control a larger one. A relay is like a switch.

Here's some [reference material](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-13-power-control/hardware) about using a relay with a microcontroller. You shouldn't have much trouble finding more material now that you know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So your question is: "How to control a bigger power source using the Arduino Nano or Micro".

This tutorial on youtube gives an explanation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOz41WQF7wE

It's about a motor, but the answer is the same.
You should use a relais/mosfet

This one is actually pretty great also:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Te5YYVZiOKs